# Can Stand users de-summon their Stand whenever they want?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure*, I've been wondering why, when a person's Stand is getting hit, they don't just unsummon it.

Can Stand users de-summon their Stand whenever they want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but in a fight, it may feel extra painful to do so.

Maybe if a stand has hold of another stand, I do not believe it can be taken back.

Example 1: Kakyoin's Hierophant Green stuck in Strength in Part 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you felt like you were being punched in the stomach, I don't think you would be able to run. Simply, the answer is no, because you would be in pain.

It is similar to stands, as stands are a physical manifestation of the soul, and they're practically just 'another body'.

Also removing your stand in the middle of a fight would be suicide.

For example, Hanged Man and Emperor did damage to people's actual bodies without touching their stands.

Answer (score 1):

#### The user must bring their Stand near their body and can't just dematerialize it.

First, I disagree with the premise that a Stand user would want to de-summon their Stand in response to it taking a hit, [for the same reasons that Palkia Catcher already covered](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/62497/73965). One comment I'll add: if the Stand's reaction time is fast enough to notice an attack about to land, the Stand could probably dodge or block instead.

While I can't point to any explicit rule that a Stand must return to its user before disappearing, I can think of several situations where being able to instantly recall a Stand would be extremely useful to the user but they don't do it, implying that **Stands don't work that way**:

- **Hanged Man** (*Stardust Crusaders* manga chapter 32 & anime episode 11): Once Polnareff and Kakyoin work out that Hanged Man moves between reflective surfaces, they're able to trap the Stand by ensuring there's only one surface for it to move to and then intercepting it. The audience even gets to see J. Geil look on in horror just before the trap is sprung, suggesting he's powerless to stop his Stand from exposing itself to harm.
- **Lovers** (*Stardust Crusaders* manga chapter 52 & anime episode 17): Kakyoin and Polnareff find a way to reach Lovers inside of Joseph's brain, so Lovers retreats. However, Steely Dan knows he has to wait for Lovers to come back to him, so he buys time by groveling at Jotaro's feet. When Dan tries to attack again, he's foiled because Hierophant Green secretly ensnared Lovers with a tentacle while in Joseph's brain. If Dan could simply dematerialize Lovers from inside of Joseph, Kakyoin's tactic wouldn't have worked.
- **Echoes vs. Sheer Heart Attack** (*Diamond is Unbreakable* manga chapters 91-92 & anime episode 23): After Koichi and Jotaro discover Sheer Heart Attack, Koichi assumes the user is nearby and sends Echoes out to try to find them. Echoes reaches the limit of its effective range to find the user is even further away than that, and at the same time SHA changes targets to Koichi. Jotaro tells Koichi to recall Echoes and defend himself, but Koichi protests that Echoes is too far away (and this is on top of Koichi acknowledging Echoes' speed when ACT2 was first revealed).

Answer (score 0):

They can't de-summon it mid-combat for, well, y'know, reasons.
I don't think you'd be able to just 'abracadabra' something connected to your body for spiritual reasons.

It's like stand users using their stand abilities, they have to consciously use it without being distracted.

TLDR: no because funny brain